# Does Scala have an API method that converts a Seq[Option[T]] to Seq[T]?

Tags: scala, scala-option

Is there a Scala API method to convert a `Seq[Option[T]] -> Seq[T]`?

You can do this manually via:

```
seq.filter(_.isDefined).map(_.get)
```

Wondering if there is a method that does the above in the general API.

Comment: `filter` + `map` can be reduced to `collect` which takes partial function as a parameter.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Absolutely, positively not. (Not!)

```
scala> val so1 = List(Some(1), None, Some(2), None, Some(3))
so1: List[Option[Int]] = List(Some(1), None, Some(2), None, Some(3))

scala> so1.flatten
res0: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: Surprisingly so1.flapMap(r => r) also works. This seems to be due to the fact that Option can be converted to an iterable through: implicit def option2Iterable[A](xo: Option[A]): Iterable[A] = xo.toList. When xo.toList is called only Some(X) generate a list value. None gives a List(). Flatmap does the rest.

Comment: Not so surprising, because `flatMap(fun)` == `map(fun).flatten`.

Comment: What do you mean by "Absolutely, positively not. (Not!)" Doesn't your code demo this working?